# LINQ Group by with dynamic multiple parameters to splits datatable as multiple datatables in C#

Tags: linq, datatable

I want to split datatables from one datatable by dynamic column name.
Now dynamic column names is not work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nameList.Count; i++)
{
    // a = r["a"]
    b += nameList[i] +"="+ "r[\"" + nameList[i] + "\"]";
    if (i != nameList.Count - 1)
    {
        b += ",";
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < nameList.Count; i++)
{
    dataTableList  = dtDataList.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row 
       => new { b}).Select(row => row.CopyToDataTable()).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you understand enough about programming or C# to accomplish this - what do you think `new { b }` means?

Comment: BTW, why are you assigning `dataTableList` over and over to the same value `nameList.Count` times?

Comment: I have to group by with dynamic column names.I cannot know end users want to group by with how much columns.So, I want to use dynamic column names of nameList.

Comment: But why are you using a loop that does nothing useful to assign `dataTableList`?

Comment: I donot know clearly the usage of linq.I want to group by columns dynamically and split datatables by grouping data.I know my usage is incorrect.So, I want to know how to do correct.